# wbadmin refuses to schedule backup

Tags: backup, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to register a scheduled backup on a Server 2019 Core (Hyper-V Server). Whenever I try to schedule a backup using wbadmin enable backup no error is thrown, but however after checking it says that no scheduled backup is existing.

The backup-target is connected via iscsi (on a Synology RS422+) and the volume is formatted as NTSF and mounted as "B:".
So far, a manual backup using wbadmin start backup ... works fine.

This is my command:
`wbadmin enable backup -addTarget:\\?\Volume{56b596ff-9729-44c4-8f69-daba8511b7ff}\ -allCritical -include:c:,d: -hyperv:11664877-6063-4F2A-ABE3-C2AA8E09F260,E2712BBE-4159-4E73-BCBC-92D3ADC14FED -schedule:03:00 -quiet -vssfull`
Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind. A reboot did the trick.